# Translate SMS Body in Android

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I am developing an application in which I want to translate an SMS body into Hindi/Gujarati from English.

Can anyone provide a free API for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft (Bing Translator) offers a free language translator (within limits) that you may want to use.

Below is a link to the Java wrapper that can be integrated into your Android application:

https://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/

However, as an alternative if you decide to go along the paid route, you can consider Google Translate's service:

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#background-concepts